# Rails ActiveRecord Sharding for B2B Application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, sharding

I have a B2B application with below requirements:

1. We are on Rails5. Mysql 5.6 is our main production DB.
2. Below is the schema for table user_preferences

   client_id, user_id, pref1, pref2,.. pref10, created_at, updated_at

   Total no of preference columns are 10. Pref fields data types are tinyint, int.
   Also there are 2 datetime fields.
3. All above data is currently stored in a single table.
4. As more and more clients are joining to our application, we are expecting this table to grow huge soon. It's possible a single client can have 10 million users.

**Question**:

1. I am looking for way to shard my tables based on client ID. e.g. client 1 has table client1_user_preferences, client2_user_preference etc. All read write queries will go to respective client user preference table.

Schema will be something like:

**client1_user_preferences**

user_id, pref1, pref2,.. pref10, created_at, updated_at

Is there a way rails activerecord support this? If there is no gem/plugin, I am open to other suggestions too.

**Why I am looking to separate tables based on Client?**

1. We have business use case to give an option to Clients to manage their own users data by moving table to their own DB after using application service. With sharded tables the migration will be very smooth.
2. Extensive read write operations are performed on this table. With this approach data per table will be less hence faster read, write queries.

Comment: First, please explain your goal behind sharding.  (Your answer may have an impact on the direction to take this.)

Comment: @RickJames Done! let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @RickJames looking for your inputs

Comment: Each client has his own database?

Comment: There is a tradeoff:  smaller table is a little faster; but involves more activity in table-cache, buffer-pool, file-opens, etc.

Comment: WordPress gives each 'user' about 12 tables.  This works fine for the first few hundred users, then it hits other issues.  I can't predict what will happen with you.

Comment: @RickJames No client doesn't have their own database. Clients are created dynamically when they signup through web app. What are the recommended solutions for this kind of use case?

Comment: I don't know enough about Rails to say whether it will help or whether it will hinder.  Sharding across multiple servers with 10s of millions of users will require a team of DBAs and Programmers; it cannot be designed and executed by one person with the help of a free forum.

Answer (score 0):

Since your aspirations are high and your budget is low, I recommend you implement *something* now.  But *plan on re-engineering the entire design within 6 months*.

The "something" you implement now will give you some feel for the pitfalls you will encounter, and teach you what needs to be fixed in the re-engineering.  And it *may* point out the limitations of the software you are using.  (Generally, big projects, have to throw out any 3rd party package that stands between the client software and the database.  It was handy for proof-of-concept, but fell apart when scaling)

And do not think that the second step is the last upheaval -- plan to *again* rebuild the *entire* system in another 6 months.

The thing that hurts big projects the most is getting stuck with an early design, yet not having the willingness to throw it out when it cannot scale further.